# How to perform 2 checks in LINQ Where

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

```
public List<SavedOption> GetValidSavedOptions(
    List<Option> itemOptions, 
    List<SavedOption> savedOptions)
{
    List<SavedOption> finalSavedOptions = savedOptions.Where(x => 
        OptionTextDoesMatch(y, x) && 
        itemOptions.Any(y => y.SomeID == x.SomeID)
    ).ToList(); 
}
```

I am totally new to LINQ and Lambdas.

In the above, what I need/want to do is include the `SavedOption` only if the call to `OptionTextDoesMatch` AND `SomeID` of the `savedOption` is found in the list of `SomeID` in `itemOptions`.  If the call to `OptionTextDoesMatch` returns `true` AND the current `savedOptions` `SavedOption.SomeID` is found in the `itemOption` collection then it will be in the `ToList()`

UPDATED:

I tried this but syntax still not working for me:

savedOptions.Where(itemOptions.Any( OptionTextDoesMatch(x,y) && (y => y.SomeID == x.SomeID))).ToList();

Now I don't know if I can just throw in x like that.  I assume if I do it's going to represent the currrent savedOption and I don't need the => ?

Comment: What's the question?  I notice that you are referencing "y" outside of the lambda expression that defines it, which wouldn't work.  In general, if you have two conditions that you want to "and" together, you can just make two different calls to Where (ie query.Where(x).Where(y)).

Comment: yea I don't know the proper way to get the OptionTextDoesMatch called here.  I need to pass in x and y to it.

Comment: OptionTextDoesMatch(SavedOption option, Option itemOption)

Comment: so I need to pass in the SavedOptoin and itemOption to that method which will return a bool.  So then I can check for that && the other case, that SomeID exists in the list of SomeID for itemOptions.  The problem I have is how to call that method OptionTextDoesMatch and pass in those params

Comment: why don't you just put both calls inside the .any(...) ? Like itemOptions.Any(y =>OptionTextDoesMatch(y, x)&& y.SomeID == x.SomeID)

Comment: "I need to pass in x and y to it."  What is y?  The only y in your query is the argument to Any (which is local to the Any lambda): do you mean the first matching itemOption?

Comment: well I read it as this.  y is the current itemOption.  x is the current savedOption.  Again, I've read about LINQ and Lambdas but I'm still NOT there yet.  I'm trying as best I can so far.

Comment: itowlson, exactly! so I"m not sure how to grab x and y at the same time and pass it to my method!

Comment: Zenon, yours might work, since now x and y will have values.  I just wonder what side effects I'll have if any moving it inside Any

Comment: nah I meant it like this:

    savedOptions.Where(x => 
        itemOptions.Any(y =>OptionTextDoesMatch(y, x) && y.SomeID == x.SomeID)

basically what dtb submitted as answer

Comment: so it doesn't matter where your doing the var => as long as it comes before the type it represents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Random guess:

```
List<SavedOption> finalSavedOptions = savedOptions.Where(x => 
    itemOptions.Any(y => OptionTextDoesMatch(y, x) && y.SomeID == x.SomeID)
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

Though the answers above are *correct*, they are "give a man a fish" answers. It would be better to take this opportunity to learn how to break down a problem into small pieces, and then reassemble the results into queries.

> In the above, what I need/want to do
>   is include the SavedOption only if the
>   call to OptionTextDoesMatch AND SomeID
>   of the savedOption is found in the
>   list of SomeID in itemOptions.

Let me try to rephrase this someone confusing sentence.

You have a list of SavedOptions. Each SavedOption has an ID and some text.

You have a list of Options. Each Option has an ID and some text.

You wish to filter the list of SavedOptions in order to get the SavedOptions which match some Option on BOTH text and ID.

Break the problem down.  Suppose you did not have a sequence of SavedOptions. Suppose you just had one SavedOption, and a list of Options. How would you tell if it was a match?

That's straightforward:

```
SavedOption mySavedOption = whatever;
bool matchExists = itemOptions.Any(item=>
    OptionTextDoesMatch(item, mySavedOption) && 
    item.SomeID == mySavedOption.SomeID);
```

Does that make sense?

Now suppose you wanted to make a *predicate* out of that which takes a SavedOption. How would you do it? That's straightforward:

```
Func<SavedOption, bool> predicate = savedOption => 
    itemOptions.Any(item=>
        OptionTextDoesMatch(item, savedOption ) && 
        item.SomeID == savedOption.SomeID);
```

This is a *predicate* which determines whether a *single* item matches.

Still making sense? Stop me if something seems confusing.

So to make a filter out of it, *apply the predicate to every item on the list of saved options*:

```
result = savedOptions.Where(savedOption => 
    itemOptions.Any(item=>
        OptionTextDoesMatch(item, savedOption) && 
        item.SomeID == savedOption.SomeID));
```

Or, in query comprehension form, which I personally find easier to read.

```
result = from savedOption in savedOptions
         where itemOptions.Any(item =>
             OptionTextDoesMatch(item, savedOption) && 
             item.SomeID == savedOption.SomeID)
         select savedOption;
```

But a possibly better choice is to use a join.  *A join is simply an optimization of a filter on the Cartesian product of two collections that are related by an id.*

```
result = from savedOption in savedOptions
         join itemOption in itemOptions 
         on savedOption.SomeID equals itemOption.SomeID
         where OptionTextDoesMatch(itemOption, savedOption)
         select savedOption;
```

Is that clear?

Comment: Okay, that was way more complicated than mine - very useful though :)  I guess mine's just the Coles notes version

Answer (score 1):

In your Where clause you are iterating each object in your savedOptions method - in a similar way as if you did:

```
foreach(SavedOption x in savedOptions)
{
    if (OptionTextDoesMatch(y, x)) //y is not yet specified...
    {
        foreach(Option y in itemOptions)
        {
            if (y.SomeID == x.SomeID)
                yield return x;
        }
    }
}
```

In your statement, the `where` clause iterates your savedOptions list and for each iteration assigns the current instance of savedOption to 'x'.  You are then checking that 'x's text matches something you haven't specified yet - 'y'.

You're then doing a second iteration: `itemOptions.Any(y => y.SomeID == x.SomeID)`.  Here, you've specified that `y` is now defined as an instance of `Option` in much the same way you did with the outer lambda expression:

```
foreach(Option y in itemOptions)
{
    return y.SomeID == x.SomeID;
}
```

Because `x` is specified by the outer clause, we've got access to it in the inner clause, but the opposite isn't true.  `y` is not specified until the inner clause, so consequently your `where` clause doesn't work.

In order to give a full diagnosis of what you're trying to do, I'd need to understand what the Option and SavedOptions objects look like and figure out what you're logically trying to do in order to explain exactly how your lambda should look...

I suspect what you're really trying to do is something like:

```
foreach(SavedOption x in savedOptions)
    foreach(Option y in itemOptions)
        if (OptionTextDoesMatch(y, x) && (y.SomeID == x.SomeID))
            yield return x;
```

Which would in lambda notation would be:

```
return savedOptions.Where(x => itemOptions.Any(y => OptionTextDoesMatch(y, x) && (y.SomeID == x.SomeID)));
```

Comment: yes, right Ben.  I get all that.  I just did not know how I could get x and y set at the same time.  THanks!

Comment: thanks Ben for your detailed explanation.  Appreciate the help.  Today was my first day of diving in with either Lambdas OR LINQ

Comment: @coffeeadict: You'll have them sorted pretty quick.  I was surprised how easy they came after a couple of days of floundering.  Then I got up one morning and they just made sense.